# How to - Flex client side and Java as Server side

Tags: java, apache-flex

Since I'm developing a multiplayer card game for Facebook using Flex as client side and Java SE as server side, I wanted to know how do I actually make the connection between Flex and Java? the server and client should be able to send each other data(cards,movement,room information etc...) across and I wonder what's the easiest way to do it without complicating it.
Any idea how to do? where to read about it ? I know JAVA but I find JavaEE hard to understand.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what have tried... some source would be good too... did you try SOAP with the built-in classes in Flex ?

Comment: @Yahia, I didn't try anything yet and have no knowledge in SOAP, I need the easiest method that can be learned quickly to be able to transfer data between the client and server and back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pay Adobe *a lot* of money and use their enterprise products.

Alternatively, you can use the open source [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS), which allows you to communicate with plain text (direct HTTP) or using the binary AMF protocol with object serialization.

Also, if you are thinking about using JSON, [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) will help you on the Flex side.

Comment: +1, Spring Flex (http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex) is an easier implementation of AMF, and if your looking at RTMP you should take a look at RED5, as it has real time messaging, remote shared objects, etc...

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler, it's easy to understand how to connect flex to an application server in Java but I still don't understand how do I take my game logic and make it an application server which gets requests and send it back, requests such: get open tables (so users can join the a table of a game), chat system, etc.

Comment: @Alon, your goal should be to split up the logic so that there is a minimal amount of network traffic without compromising game play. In general, the server should manage authentication, data storage, and probably client state so that a player can re-join a game and continue playing. The client should manage the basic game logic and sending information to the server to be stored. The client is, of course, the user interface, so all of that needs to be there. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler, Thank you very much for all your answers, In my java course they have though us how to use serversockets, etc..to establish a connection between a server and a client and use the function called accept(); to wait for users to log in, and since I only know this way of making a game server, I find all the new stuff not very clear. I read about integrating Flex with BlazeDS, spring, hibernate etc.. but I don't understand how to build a strong server with all the annotations.

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler,  Is there a place I can read about building a simple game server in JAVAEE that manages players connecting to it and create threads for the rooms of the game and connects to MySQL DB for storing and retreiving user saved data(score,name ,etc). ?

Comment: @Alon: Generally, you don't mix EE with rolling your own ServerSockets. I would probably take this opportunity to learn how to use ServerSockets instead of using an EE server, but I suppose that depends on what you want to get out of your course. If you want to go the EE route, I would suggest finding a good tutorial on using Jetty. If you're feeling adventurous, you could learn Hibernate, but there's nothing wrong with using straight JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

using SOAP as it is built into Flex already seems the easiest way to got...

For some information/example see

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_3.html
http://www.blackpepper.co.uk/black-pepper-blog/How-to-use-SOAP-web-services-with-Flex.html
http://www.blackpepper.co.uk/black-pepper-blog/How-to-use-SOAP-web-services-with-Java-and-Flex-Part-2-of-2.html